# Pass array to function without so it would not change original array no matter what

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a function that performs some magic on the array that I am passing. But the original array should be intact. Unfortunately it is changing its content based on what is happening in the array.

Can you help me, please?

Function:

```
void test(int* array) {
    array[0] = 1; // EDIT: Added missing line
    std::cout << "Inside: " << array[0] << endl;
}

int main() {
    int *testArray = new int[1];
    testArray[0] = 0;
    std::cout<<testArray[0]<<endl;
    test(testArray);
    std::cout << "Outside: " << testArray[0] << endl;
}
```

Current result is:

> 0
>
> Inside: 1
>
> Outside: 1

Result I would want to have:

> 0
>
> Inside: 1
>
> Outside: 0

Is this possible?

Comment: ***const*** is the word you need

Comment: That said, it sounds like you want to pass the array by value, not by reference. This is actually kind of tricky to do with an array. Probably the easiest way to do it is use `std::vector`, but it that is forbidden, wrap the array in a structure and observe [The Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: It does not seem like const would be a good fit here @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ as OP wants to edit the array in the called function.

Comment: Why are using `new` & `delete` ? I don't see any fair reason to use them here in your code

Comment: I have missed a line. I am sorry for the mistake. First line of method test() should be: array[0] = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: As others have pointed out, it seems like you want to either pass the array *by value* instead of *by reference*, thus copying the elements of the array and modifying only the copy, or you want to avoid modifying any part of the array altogether. I'll elaborate on both parts a bit more:

In C++, there is near to no distinction between arrays and pointers. Note that both your variable `testArray` and your parameter `array` are pointers to the beginning of an array. If you use `array` to modify any part of the underlying array, what you actually do is modify the memory are that is described by both `testArray` **and** `array`. If you don't want to modify any part of the array at all, it would be helpful to use the `const` qualifier, as Destructor already wrote in his answer. If you however want to keep the original array but still want to make some modifications inside the function, the following still applies:

To keep the array from being modified, the only general way that works is to copy all of its elements by creating a new array of the same size, copying all elements from the input array to the copy and then working only on the copy, which should be deleted after the function has finished.

**My personal answer:**
I would recommend that you look into some of C++'s data structures, especially `std::vector`. If you pass it by value (not by reference), vector takes care of all the necessary copy operations I just described and in all cases, you can use it in the same way as an array, while it provides lots of additional features (i.e. dynamic size, deletion and insertion of elements, simplified iteration, ...).

Comment: I'd discard the comparison between arrays and pointers. It will bring you grief. Arrays decay to pointers. That's about all.

Comment: But (statically sized) arrays, if they are not decayed, still carry their size information in their type, which can often be helpful (see for example the std::array implementation) or every quesion of the type "How can I find the size of my array" ;)

Comment: The "long answer" is needlessly confusing because OP is passing a pointer as argument to a function that has a pointer parameter. @user4581301 is right, but even arrays decaying to pointers is irrelevant in this case, because it isn't happening.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm open to suggestions - Do you think talking only about pointers would help? I was under the impression that OP uses pointers to represent arrays without explicitly differentiating between them.

Comment: If it were relevant, personally I would remove the first sentence of the "long answer", and then write something to the effect that the function takes a pointer and has no way of knowing whether it points to an element of an array. OTOH, the first two points of the answer seem misguided, because the data pointed to can be made "read only" by simply passing a pointer to `const`, as shown in @destructor's answer.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of the first two points, thus I rewrote the first part and mentioned the `const`ness approach as well, as I am not sure if OP wants to modify the array at all.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to pass array by value not by reference. You are passing pointer to a first element here. So, any changes which you perform to that array inside that function will be reflected to original array.

The other problem is you haven't posted fair amount of code regarding the problem you want to solve. I am assuming you want functionality like this.

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/QUBFA94378).

```
#include <iostream>
void test(const int*  array) {
    array[0]=1; 
    std::cout << "Inside: " << array[0] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int *testArray = new int[1];
    testArray[0] = 0;
    std::cout<<testArray[0]<<std::endl;
    test(testArray);
    std::cout << "Outside: " << testArray[0] << std::endl;
    delete[] testArray;
}
```

Compiler will give you following errors:

```
Error(s):
source_file.cpp:4:13: error: read-only variable is not assignable
    array[0]=1;
    ~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

You should not use `new[]` to allocate dynamic arrays in C++. 99% of the time you should be using [***std::vector***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) If you want dynamic array in C++.

Comment: "When you pass C style array as a parameter to a function it decays to pointer to first element." Almost correct, but in any case irrelevant, because OP is passing a pointer. There's no pointer decay going on.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks for your input. You are right. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: You still kept the irrelevant/confusing part.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using C compatibility features...

```
void test( std::array<int, 1> a )
{
    a[0] = 1; // fine
    std::cout << "Inside: " << a[0] << endl;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 1> testArray;
    testArray[0] = 0;
    std::cout<<testArray[0]<<endl;
    test(testArray);
    std::cout << "Outside: " << testArray[0] << endl;
}
```

If you need the size determined at runtime, use `std::vector` instead of `std::array`.